# Реализация Varlong в Node.js

Tags: node.js, buffer

Мне уже удалось реализовать `Varint` в Node.js следующим образом

```
export class Varint {

  private readonly SEGMENT_BITS = 0x7f
  private readonly CONTINUE_BIT = 0x80
  protected readonly maxLength: number = 32

  read(data: Buffer): [result: number, offset: number] {
    let result = 0
    let offset = 0
    let position = 0
    let currentByte: number

    while (true) {
      currentByte = data.readInt8(offset)
      offset++
      result |= (currentByte & this.SEGMENT_BITS) << position
      if ((currentByte & this.CONTINUE_BIT) === 0) break
      position += 7
      if (position >= this.maxLength)
        throw new Error('Varint is too big')
    }
    return [result, offset]
  }

  write(value: number): Buffer {
    let buf = Buffer.alloc(0)
    while (true) {
      if ((value & ~this.SEGMENT_BITS) == 0) {
        buf = Buffer.concat([buf, Buffer.from([value])])
        break
      }
      buf = Buffer.concat([
        buf,
        Buffer.from([(value & this.SEGMENT_BITS) | this.CONTINUE_BIT])
      ])
      value >>>= 7
    }
    return buf
  }
}
```

Мне нужно реализовать `Varlong` также, но с использованием `bigint` и максимальной длины `64`, но я наткнулся на проблему, она заключается в том, что `bigint` не работает с оператором `>>>`, а `Buffer.from` не принимает массив с элементом `bigint`

Comment: Неясен смысл всего этого действия. Учитывая что в js битовые операции работаю только с 32-битными числами у вас в принципе получился довольно бесполезный класс

Comment: И каков в нём смысл при наличии BigInt тоже неясно

Comment: Я работаю с протоколом Minecraft и мне необходимо кодировать bigint в последовательность байт и обратно как Varlong

Comment: Ну сдвиг на 7 отлично заменяется умножием/делением на 128. А преобразование делается функцией Number

Comment: О, так и сдвиг работает. `1n << 7n === 128n`

Comment: Я про zero-fill right shift `>>>`

Comment: Ну да, он для BigInt не имеет смысла по причине другого формата. Наверное проще сразу привести отрицательное число к положительному (написать свой аналог операции `>>>0`)